# How to check Database Compatibility Level SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How i can know compatibility level of my current SQL database ?  Which command 
is used for that ?
For Exam : Compatibility Level 70 - 80 -90

Comment: Try this: `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases; ` [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level)

Comment: Ya you are right . Thanks

Comment: please mark as answer if it was :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this: `SELECT name, compatibility_level FROM sys.databases;`  [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-compatibility-level)

Answer (score 0):

**For SQL 2005 & newer:**

```
SELECT name, compatibility_level from sys.databases WHERE name = 'DatabaseNameHere'
```

**For SQL 2000:**

```
SELECT name, cmptlevel from sysdatabases WHERE name = 'DatabaseNameHere'
```

If you want to see the compatibility for all databases of the instance, just leave off the `WHERE` clause.

Ref: http://sqlrus.com/2014/10/compatibility-level-vs-database-version/