# How to check Compatibility level at a MySQL DataBase

Tags: mysql, sql, database, compatibility

I'm using a MySQL database, version 5.7.22, with a InnoDB engine.

I'd like to know if there is a thing as "compatibility level" like that used by SQL Server which has values such as (90, 100, 110, 120) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565769/how-to-check-database-compatibility-level-sql-server).

Thanks.

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are *completely* different RDBMS. You can't apply logic for how the framework of one works to the other.

Comment: Please tag your question properly!  "I'm using MySQL 5.7.22".  Why do I see `sql-server` tag then???  They're 2 completely different products.

Comment: Because the OP thinks that MySQL has compatibility levels, like SQL Server, it seems, @Eric .

Comment: As far as I know, MySQL has no such thing.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? i.e. if there was such a thing how do you intend to use it? Maybe there is some other solution...